# How can --enable-preview be enabled for all Gradle submodules so that it retains in IntelliJ IDEA too?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, preview

With the following Gradle setting

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.12
targetCompatibility = 1.12

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.incremental = true
    options.compilerArgs
```

the project will be compiled, the tests executed and the artifacts built on JDK 12.
However, in IntelliJ with the following common project structure

```
project
|_moduleA
  |_main
  |_test
|_moduleB
  |_main
  |_test
```

and language level set to **12 (Preview) - Switch expressions** only the project and the two modules get this language level. The **main** and **test** modules however lose the setting and IDEA says that the settings will be lost when the Gradle project will be refreshed.
So how can the **--enable-preview** setting be applied so that also the source modules keep the setting?

Comment: [It works](https://i.imgur.com/LcgQTCV.png) with language level `12 (no new language features)`. `12 (preview)` is not supported by Gradle yet. Try the [2019.1 beta version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) version if it doesn't work for you in 2018.3 release. [Related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200786).

Comment: I had this same issue with maven compiler plugin, I include --enable-preview as compilerArgs, but when reimport, it changes module language level in intellij from 12 (preview) to 12 (no new language features), drove me crazy having to switch it back, until I unchecked Import Maven projects automatically.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, solved following the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:feature_preview):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
```